# Passing an argument with an NSTimer and from a regular call to the same method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

I need to pass an integer to my method `startEvent:`. The method is a timer's action method. I've read about how to pass data with `userInfo`, however I don't understand how to do that so I can still call the method as I'd normally do.

How do I pass integers from an `NSTimer` and from a regular call to the same method?

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.032f target:self selector:@selector(startEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[self startEvent: 0];

-(void)startEvent:(int) event {
// ...
}
```

Comment: The `startEvent:` method requires one parameter with a type of `NSTimer` to support the way you setup the timer.

Comment: What value do you expect for `event` each time the timer fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pass-through for the timer's action method:

```
- (void)startEventFromTimer:(NSTimer *)tim
{
    [self startEvent:[[tim userInfo] intValue]];
}
```

Where your timer was created with an `NSNumber` for its user info object.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.032f 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(startEventFromTimer:) 
                               userInfo:@(theIntYouWantToPass)
                                repeats:NO];
```

Comment: This would require the timer having been setup with the proper `userInfo` (which it isn't).

Comment: My last sentence, @rmaddy: "Where your timer was created with an `NSNumber` for its user info object." However, I've added the code for completeness's sake.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow didn't notice the last sentence. Even with that though, the OP's request doesn't make much sense since it means the timer will send the same value every time. Kind of pointless.

Comment: No problem, @rmaddy. For the OP's request, I'm assuming the int to be passed is in an ivar or something along those lines.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Shouldn't your callback method invalidate the timer?

Comment: It's a non-repeating timer, @jlehr; it invalidates itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from a fundamental misunderstanding.  Your method **cannot** be the timers action method unless it conforms to the documented signature.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

The only opportunity you have to pass additional information in is via the userinfo object, as Josh Caswells answer demonstrates.